# How to change the default notification title?

Tags: java, android

Normally(default) notification title is a app name. But i need to change it. is it possible? how can i do it? This is default notification title. it is a app name. I need change it

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you refer to as "notification title" is not the notification title, but the name of the app the notification belongs to.
You can't change that. It is set by the OS.

Comment: Thankz for your answer.